# create a server to listen on a specific port.

Tags: python, django, tcp, udp

I want to create a website a django which will be hosted on Apache. I also want my server to keep listening on a port and if some data comes on the port then process it. 
Processing and website part is all doable by me but I have no Idea about how to make the server with a listing port and then forward the data to my python code. how is this done ? can anyone give me a tutorial or a pointer.

Thank you.

Comment: You have to use `mod_wsgi` to run Django application on apache.

Comment: @Lafada would that take care of listing to a specific port continuously ?

Comment: You have to configure `Apache` on specific port.

Comment: Thank you. I will start doing that.

Comment: Here is how: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `VirtualHost` directive of `Apache`.

```
<VirtualHost *:8080>
    ServerName www.example.com
    WSGIScriptAlias / /path/to/script.wsgi

    <Location /my/location>
    ...
    </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```